# Unable to post object Or list of object to same method wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating a single post method in wcf service on which an app can push response for any command send by my website.

Response can be in form of single object or list of objects. Like Handset details and list of apps installed in handset.

Below are my DTOs

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(HandsetInfoReceiveDTO))]
[KnownType(typeof(List<ApplicationReceiveDTO>))]
public class CommandReceiveDTO : MessageCommandDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CommandKey { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MAC { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public CommandReceiveBaseDTO Response { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class HandsetInfoReceiveDTO : CommandReceiveBaseDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Battery { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Wifi { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ApplicationReceiveDTO : CommandReceiveBaseDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public string AppName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class CommandReceiveBaseDTO
{

}
```

Service Method

```
public ResponseDTO<bool> ReceiveCommandResponseFromDevice(CommandReceiveDTO ObjResponse)
    {
        ResponseDTO<bool> Result = new ResponseDTO<bool>();
        return Result;
    }
```

Help JSON code generated from service

```
{
"MessageCommandId":9223372036854775807,
"CommandKey":"String content",
"MAC":"String content",
"Response":{
    "__type":"HandsetInfoReceiveDTO:#CommandService.DTO.Commands.Receive",
    "Battery":2147483647,
    "Wifi":true
}}
```

Now the issue is that it is not working in case i send list of ApplicationReceiveDTO. 
I got the reference from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types) ,but does not show any example of list of object.

As of today i tried changing

```
[DataMember]
    public CommandReceiveBaseDTO Response { get; set; }
```

To

```
[DataMember]
    public List<CommandReceiveBaseDTO> Response { get; set; }
```

Then it accepts json as list but not a single object.

Ultimately i need a single method which could hold a object and list of objects. 
Any help will surely save my time.

Comment: You must create two separate methods, one for a single object and other to a list of objects, or another option is always receive a list, and if you want to send one object add only one to the list

Comment: @RicardoPontual, It could be very hard to digest if there is not other way except creating two separate methods.. I was very positive to find a way out of this situation

Comment: A method must be clear about its contract, a parameter can be an object or a list of objects. Service interfaces doens't allow overloading, so you cannot have two methods with same same, so the solution I can see is always receive a list, and handle differently if the list contais only one object or more.